# find data dictionary behind URL

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Find data dictionary behind URL

https://www.coingecko.com/fr/pi%C3%A8ces/1/markets_tab --> BTC

https://www.coingecko.com/fr/pi%C3%A8ces/2/markets_tab --> LTC

https://www.coingecko.com/fr/pi%C3%A8ces/3/markets_tab --> AUR

https://www.coingecko.com/fr/pi%C3%A8ces/?/markets_tab --> ?

https://www.coingecko.com/fr/pi%C3%A8ces/100/markets_tab --> XLM

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import requests 

i = 0
while(True):
try:
    if i == 0:
        url = "https://www.coingecko.com/fr/pi%C3%A8ces/1/markets_tab"
    else:
        url = "https://www.coingecko.com/fr/pi%C3%A8ces/{}/markets_tab".format(i)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    print(url)
    sleep(2)
    i += 2
except:
    break
```

I want to scan all numbers from 1 to 100 in order to find the associate coin using python.

Comment: "I want to scan all numbers from 1 to 100 in order to find the associate coin using python" - fantastic, good luck! If you happen to get stuck with your code, feel free to ask here!

Comment: @ForceBru sorry I just edited my question with the code

Comment: What's your question? Your code looks fine, although it will skip all odd numbers except 1 because you're incrementing `i` by 2.

Comment: @ForceBru what you want to do ? print the coin names?

Comment: Each number is linked to a coin. The coin name's is in the HTML source code. I would like to create a dataframe combining these two data. ex: 1->BTC, 2->LTC, 3->AUR, ..

Answer (score 0):

IDK what you are looking for. your question is unclear. anyway using the following code, you should be able to loop and then you can do what you want.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as req:
    for item in range(1, 101):
        r = req.get(f"https://www.coingecko.com/fr/pi%C3%A8ces/{}/markets_tab")
        if r.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            # Do whatever.
```